# Processing payment with Stripe and updating MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, stripe-payments

I am new to MongoDB and Stripe. I am having a difficult time finding a way to update a MongoDB value upon completing a successful Stripe payment. I can't figure out where to even begin. I'm not sure to how to setup the connection "string" if you will to enable this app to the talk the database and update the value. Can someone please help me or help point me in the right direction?

Here is my server side stripe information in **Node**:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_*******************');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());

app.post('/charge', function(req, res) {
    var stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;
    var amount = 1000;

    stripe.charges.create({
        card: stripeToken,
        currency: 'usd',
        amount: amount
    },
    function(err, charge) {
        console.log(req.user);
        if (err) {
            res.send(500, err);
        } else {
            res.send(204);
        }
    });
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8082);
```

I'm thinking in the successful response I will connect to the database and update the value. When a new user has registered, I will set the default value of has paid to 0 and then a 1 upon successful payment.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'll want to do in this case is establish a connection to your MongoDB database somewhere under where you set the API Key.  Then under there, create another function that does some kind of [MongoDB Update](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/update/) operation on your database.

Then, in the callback of your Create Charge request (ie. the `console.log(req.user);`-line) call your new function.

The MongoDB documentation goes over a little bit about how to do this in Node.JS and what to use for your connection string in the link I attached earlier; however, if the database is on your local machine, it is probably as simple as `mongodb://localhost:27017/{YOURCOLLECTIONAMEHERE}`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the response. But how am I supposed to send the user information in the request?